# iOS Enterprise Provisioning Profiles: How many can I have?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

If I'm part of Apple's Enterprise program, is there a limit to the number of enterprise provisioning profiles I can make?

Is there any additional cost per profile?

Finally, is it advisable to only use one profile per app (or one profile per third-party app developer)?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to figure out (for a client) whether a third-party vendor they're using needs to use their existing provisioning profile, or whether they can create a new enterprise one. (The latter would be much easier in this case, due to private key woes.) I've read the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW34) and I've googled a bit, but I'm not sure I've found my answer yet.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you/they trying to achieve with the vendor provisioning profiles?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Honestly, I'm not sure. I think that they might be trying to move away from the original app vendor. If that's the case, would there be any issue with having the app vendor create the enterprise profile and certificate for current distribution? Would we have any troubles taking over that provisioning profile and certificate later? (My hunch says no - we can edit the profile, add devices if necessary, and we'd only need to renew the certificate after a year, meaning we could generate a new one with our private key.)

Comment: Technically, as long as they have an enterprise account, using the vendor's certificate should be fine. Not so sure about contractually. Changing to your own later, should be fine, although you may need to change bundleID, e.g. if you're not using wildcard/are using push notifications or other things that depend on entitlements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm part of Apple's Enterprise program, is there a limit to the number of enterprise provisioning profiles I can make?

I'm guessing there is an upper limit, but it's high.  Enterprise distribution profiles expire every year, so there may be a lot.

> Is there any additional cost per profile?

No.  But you probably should consider using wildcard profiles where possible to simplify things (you have to re-sign all apps once a year).  You can't do this if you use Apple's services though (iCloud, push notifications, etc.)

We've had success having the vendor submit xcarchive files instead of giving them full access to a distribution profile.  You create a development profile for the vendor using the same bundle ID as your distribution profile and have them build an archive using the development profile (seems counterintuitive, but it works).  Your vendor can then export an xcarchive and submit it to you.  You can import this xcarchive into Xcode's organizer and then generate and sign the ipa like normal.

This process completely removes the risks of giving a 3rd party your distribution profile.  All they have is a developer profile that you can revoke.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct, as it may greatly simplify the situation we're in now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use one provisioning profile per app - it will make it much easier to manage entitlements like push notifications, etc.

I've never hit a limit on creating provisioning profiles. I've seen lots get created automatically by Xcode, which creates clutter but nothing worse.